# Django force password expiration

Tags: django, passwords

Are there any django apps for force expiring the password of the user after certain interval like 30 days? I am using djangp's auth and want to extend it or use a community app.

What I have tried so far:

1. Added a field to user profile for storing the date of last password updated.
2. Extended the login method to check for this date and redirect the user to password change page.

What I am confused about:

1. To block the user accessing the site till the password is changed.
2. User should not be able to login or just type urls to access the page directly.

Please note that I don't want to use middleware as it will be a resource constraint.

Comment: Stealing @DanielRoseman's excellent comment from [a related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450358/django-force-user-password-reset-expiration): "_enforcing regular password changes is no longer recommended; e.g., by the UK's [NCSC](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/blog-post/problems-forcing-regular-password-expiry), the [FTC](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/blogs/techftc/2016/03/time-rethink-mandatory-password-changes), etc._"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem on the right track. Set the date of the last password updated, check if the timedelta  is greater than 30 days, if so redirect to the change password page. Your Login view should essentially stay the same except don't actually login the user to the request object if the timedelta is greater than 30 days.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            if date.today() - user.password_date > timedelta(days=30):
                # Redirect to password change page
            else:
                login(request, user)
                # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
    # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

Comment: How does it block the user from accessing other views?

Comment: You can probably accomplish this with middleware too, and this approach would apply site wide.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is django-passwords-policies-iplweb, https://github.com/iplweb/django-password-policies-iplweb, which is a friendly maitained fork of http://tarak.github.io/django-password-policies/ , which is currently not maintained.

Comment: I tried using this but it appears it is not maintained anymore. It is not compatible anymore with the latest django version (2.1 as of this comment was written)

Comment: This package has not been maintained since 2016.

Comment: Try my friendly fork instead then. https://github.com/iplweb/django-password-policies-iplweb