# Django - force user password reset/expiration

Tags: django, authentication

The task I want to accomplish is to force users to regularly change their passwords. I've implemented all the standard password change, reset, etc functionalities which are built in with `django.contrib.auth.forms`.

Which leads to the following issues:

- If I redirect them to the reset workflow it will change the password and I have not found a way to update my `password_changed` timestamp in my custom user model since the functionality is built into Django.
- I could redirect them to the password change view (which also uses a builtin form), but if the user is not logged in (which would be counter productive in this case), the user attribute in the request is `None`.

Am I overcomplicating things? Could someone give me a hint how to implement this?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093593/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-change-password-at-next-logon-type-feature-in-th

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571046/django-force-password-expiration

Comment: You might find some interesting ideas in https://github.com/tarak/django-password-policies (but the last update is from 2016,  so it probably is not up to date with the newest django versions)

Comment: Note, enforcing regular password changes is no longer recommended, eg by the UK's [NCSC](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/blog-post/problems-forcing-regular-password-expiry), the [FTC](https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/blogs/techftc/2016/03/time-rethink-mandatory-password-changes), etc.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the easiest way so far:
Check the status during the login-in process, set the password to an unusable pw value if the user hasn't changed his password and force him to use the password reset functionality.

The downside of this is that I haven't found a way to reset the password_change timestamp during the reset workflow (since its built in) and so the timestamp has to be set during the login check...

Thanks!